# Where does npm install packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, location, npm

Can someone tell me where can I find the Node.js modules, which I installed using **`npm`**?

Comment: on linux mint it's `$HOME/.npm-global/lib/node_modules`

Comment: Just so every one knows, installing without `-g` option will install a module to you working directory e.g. if you make a directory say `~/Desktop/tmp` then `cd ~/Desktop/tmp` then do `npm install appium` then do `ls` you will see `node_modules     package-lock.json` because you have installed a node module `appium` to your `working directory`... super confusing because `-g` should essentially be the `default` but is not.

Comment: ```npm config get prefix``` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32159233/2361131)

Comment: When using nvm to manage multiple versions of node, it's under `$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v15.9.0/lib` where the directory will change depending on what version of node you are using.  See https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md for more info on nvm.  I found this directory with `npm list -g | head -1` as stated in the selected answer.

Answer (score 1620, accepted):

## Global libraries

You can run `npm list -g` to see which global libraries are installed and where they're located. Use `npm list -g | head -1` for truncated output showing just the path. If you want to display only main packages not its sub-packages which installs along with it - you can use - `npm list --depth=0` which will show all packages and for getting only globally installed packages, just add -g i.e. `npm list -g --depth=0`.

On Unix systems they are normally placed in `/usr/local/lib/node` or `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` when installed globally. If you set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable to this path, the modules can be found by node.

Windows XP - `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\npm\node_modules`
Windows 7, 8 and 10 - `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

## Non-global libraries

Non-global libraries are installed the `node_modules` sub folder in the folder you are currently in.

You can run `npm list` to see the installed non-global libraries for your current location.

## When installing use -g option to install globally

**`npm install -g pm2`** - pm2 will be installed globally. It will then typically be found in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` (Use **`npm root -g`** to check where.)

**`npm install pm2`** - pm2 will be installed locally. It will then typically be found in the local directory in `/node_modules`

Comment: If you're using nvm, then your global modules may be in one of several places depending on the version of node you're using at the time.  The best way is to use `npm list -g` as suggested in another answer.

Comment: does not work for me, shows only bin folder.  "npm root -g" does work.

Comment: under Arch linux, the global modules are under /usr/lib.
"npm --help" shows the exact location as last line of the output, e.g.:
npm@3.6.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm

Comment: This is incorrect for non-global modules.  Non-global modules are not installed in ./node_modules, but into an "appropriate" node_modules directory in the current directory or a parent directory, based on the presence of "node_modules" or "package.json".  The upshot is that this can wind up being several directories above the current directory.  See "More information" under https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders.

Comment: and maybe placed in `/usr/lib/node_modules`

Comment: for windows 10,placed in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

Comment: "npm root -g" is correct - list might work but is far too much info, where as the other command just gives you the exact location you are looking for.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24295332/174965

Comment: `npm root` alone is pointless. If there's a `node_modules` in your working directory it will show it -- *just like* `ls`. Always use `npm root -g`

Comment: At least on Windows, the location where packages are installed is not the same as the "bin" directory. So the directory to add to your path would be `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Comment: Both for XP and Vista, 7, 8, 10 `%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules` points to the correct folder. `%APPDATA%` equals `C:\Documents and Settings\{username}\Application Data` in XP and `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming` from Vista to 10.

Comment: I found it on `/usr/lib/` (there's a `node_modules` in it).

Comment: Regarding "*Non-global libraries are installed the `node_modules` sub folder in the folder you are currently in.*" ... **to my observation, this is not correct**. `npm install somepackage` will use the same directory as the one returned by executing `npm root`. The logic seems to be: "from the *current working directory* (`./`), if it doesn't have a directory `./node_modules/`, iteratively go up the parent directory chain until a directory `node_modules/` is found. If none is found after checking the root directory `/`, *then* choose `./node_modules/` in the *current working directory*.

Answer (score 735):

The command `npm root` will tell you the effective installation directory of your npm packages.

If your current working directory is a node package or a sub-directory of a node package, `npm root` will tell you the local installation directory. `npm root -g` will show the global installation root regardless of current working directory.

### Example:

```
$ npm root -g
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

[See the documentation.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/root.html)

Comment: Follow up question: does npm install -g do anything besides move these files to that location (I am using Red Hat if that matters), such as run a chmod command?
I am trying to make a docker container that uses these modules, but does not use npm install (long story)

Comment: Very helpful if you use `nvm` as you may have multiple locations per node version, e.g. `~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/lib/node_modules`

Answer (score 116):

### For globally-installed modules:

The other answers give you platform-specific responses, but a generic one is this:

When you install global module with `npm install -g something`, npm looks up a config variable `prefix` to know where to install the module.

You can get that value by running **`npm config get prefix`**

To display all the global modules available in that folder use `npm ls -g --depth 0` (`depth 0` to not display their dependencies).

If you want to change the global modules path, use `npm config edit` and put `prefix = /my/npm/global/modules/prefix` in the file or use `npm config set prefix /my/npm/global/modules/prefix`.

When you use some tools like [nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist), they change the platform-default installation path of global npm modules.

Comment: You answered my follow-up question: "Can someone tell me how I can *change* the location of the Node.js modules?"
_Note: The reason why this was important to me was so that I didn't have to change my PATH yet again.  I uncommented the default suggestion in the npmrc file that {npm config get prefx} opens._

Answer (score 72):

On windows I used `npm list -g` to find it out. By default my (global) packages were being installed to `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

Comment: Just FYI - This is the executing user's %appdata%\npm

Answer (score 30):

If you are looking for the executable that npm installed, maybe because you would like to put it in your PATH, you can simply do

```
npm bin
```

or

```
npm bin -g
```

Comment: If you've globally installed npm packages where node was installed with homebrew and then npm updated with npm itself, you may be getting `command not found` errors. If so, add the aboveto your PATH: `export PATH=$PATH:$(npm bin -g)` voila

Comment: `npm bin` has been removed since [v9.0.0](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.0.0)

Comment: Any replacement?

Answer (score 24):

If a module was installed with the global (`-g`) flag, you can get the parent location by running:

```
npm get prefix
```

or

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

which will print the location along with the list of installed modules.

Answer (score 22):

Not direct answer but may help ....

The npm also has a cache folder, which can be found by running `npm config get cache` (`%AppData%/npm-cache` on Windows).

The npm modules are first downloaded here and then copied to npm global folder (`%AppData%/Roaming/npm` on Windows) or project specific folder (`your-project/node_modules`).

So if you want to track npm packages, and some how, the list of all downloaded npm packages (if the npm cache is not cleaned)  have a look at this folder. The folder structure is as `{cache}/{name}/{version}`

This may help also https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

Answer (score 19):

In earlier versions of NPM modules were always placed in /usr/local/lib/node or wherever you specified the npm root within the .npmrc file. However, in NPM 1.0+ modules are installed in two places. You can have modules installed local to your application in /.node_modules or you can have them installed globally which will use the above.

More information can be found at https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/doc/install.md

Comment: Something to note- with 1.0 modules are stored in /usr/local/lib/node_modules.

Comment: @EricSmith your link is broken too

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 | Page not found"*.

Answer (score 19):

To get a compact list without dependencies simply use

```
npm list -g --depth 0
```

Answer (score 17):

As the other answers say, the best way is to do

```
npm list -g
```

However, if you have a large number of `npm` packages installed, the output of this command could be very long and a big pain to scroll up (sometimes it's not even possible to scroll that far back).

In this case, pipe the output to the `more` program, like this

```
npm list -g | more
```

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way would be to do

> npm list -g

to list the package and view their installed location.

I had installed npm via chololatey, so the location is

C:\MyProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.commandline.0.10.31\tools\node_modules

C:\MyProgramData\ is chocolatey repo location.

Answer (score 15):

- Echo the config: `npm config ls` or `npm config list`
- Show all the config settings: `npm config ls -l` or `npm config ls --json`
- Print the effective **node_modules** folder: `npm root` or `npm root -g`
- Print the local prefix: `npm prefix` or `npm prefix -g`

  (This is the closest parent directory to contain a **package.json** file or **node_modules** directory)

---

- [npm-config | npm Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/config.html)
- [npm-root | npm Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/root.html)
- [npm-prefix | npm Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/prefix.html)

Answer (score 12):

I was beginning to go mad while searching for the real configuration, so here is the list of all configuration files on linux:

- /etc/npmrc
- /home/youruser/.npmrc
- /root/.npmrc
- ./.npmrc in the current directory next to package.json file (thanks to @CyrillePontvieux)

on windows:

- c/Program\ Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/npmrc

Then in this file the prefix is configured:

```
prefix=/usr
```

The prefix is defaulted to /usr in linux, to ${APPDATA}\npm in windows

The node modules are under $prefix tree, and the path should contain $prefix/bin

There may be a problem :

- When you install globally, you use "sudo su" then the `/root/.npmrc` may be used!
- When you use locally without sudo: for your user its the `/home/youruser/.npmrc`.
- When your path doesn't represent your prefix
- When you use `npm set -g prefix /usr` it sets the /etc/npmrc global, but doesn't override the local

Here is all the informations that were missing to find what is configured where. Hope I have been exhaustive.

Comment: `/root/.npmrc` should never be search for because `sudo` with `npm` is a bad practice even if some tutorial mention it.
You forgot to mention `.npmrc` in the directory next to `package.json` file.

Answer (score 10):

You can find ***globally*** installed modules by the command

```
npm list -g
```

It will provide you the location where node.js modules have been installed.

```
C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

If you install node.js modules ***locally*** in a folder, you can type the following command to see the location.

```
npm list
```

Answer (score 9):

Expanding upon other answers.

```
npm list -g
```

will show you the location of globally installed packages.

If you want to output that list to a file that you can then easily search in your text editor:

```
npm list -g > ~/Desktop/npmfiles.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/):

> In npm 1.0, there are two ways to install things:
>
> - globally —- This drops modules in `{prefix}/lib/node_modules`, and puts executable files in `{prefix}/bin`, where `{prefix}` is usually
>     something like `/usr/local`. It also installs man pages in
>     `{prefix}/share/man`, if they’re supplied.
> - locally —- This installs your package in the current working directory. Node modules go in `./node_modules`, executables go in
>     `./node_modules/.bin/`, and man pages aren’t installed at all.

You can get your `{prefix}` with `npm config get prefix`. (Useful when you installed node with nvm).

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders):

> Packages are dropped into the node_modules folder under the prefix.
>   When installing locally, this means that you can
>   require("packagename") to load its main module, or
>   require("packagename/lib/path/to/sub/module") to load other modules.
>
> Global installs on Unix systems go to {prefix}/lib/node_modules.
>   Global installs on Windows go to {prefix}/node_modules (that is, no
>   lib folder.)
>
> Scoped packages are installed the same way, except they are grouped
>   together in a sub-folder of the relevant node_modules folder with the
>   name of that scope prefix by the @ symbol, e.g. npm install
>   @myorg/package would place the package in
>   {prefix}/node_modules/@myorg/package. See scope for more details.
>
> If you wish to require() a package, then install it locally.

You can get your `{prefix}` with `npm config get prefix`. (Useful when you installed node with nvm).

Read about [locally](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally).
Read about [globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally).

Answer (score 4):

***Windows 10***: When I ran `npm prefix -g`, I noticed that the install location was inside of the git shell's path that I used to install. Even when that location was added to the path, the command from the globally installed package would not be recognized. Fixed by:

1. running `npm config edit`
2. changing the prefix to 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm'
3. adding that path to the system path variable
4. reinstalling the package with -g.

Comment: Thanks sir, this was the real problem I was stuck into

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 14.04 they are installed at

`/usr/lib/node_modules`

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 7, 8 and 10 -
`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

**Note**:

If you are somewhere in folder type `cd ..` until you are in `C:` directory. Then, type `cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`. Then, magically, `%USERPROFILE%` will change into `Users\YourUserProfile\`.

I just wanted to clarify on ideas referred by `Decko` in the first response. `npm list -g` will list all the bits you have globally installed. If you need to find your project related `npm package` then `cd 'your angular project xyz'`, then run `npm list`. It will show list of modules in `npm package`. It will also give you list of `dependencies` missing, and you may require to effectively run that project.

Comment: Note that if have a fresh install of npm on a Windows system (not sure about linux), npm won't actually make the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules folder until you install a global package for the first time

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access your global dir from code, you can backtrack from [`process.execPath`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execpath). For example, to find `wsproxy`, which is in `{NODE_GLOBAL_DIR}/bin/wsproxy`, you can just:

```
path.join(path.dirname(process.execPath), 'wsproxy')
```

There's also how the `npm` cli works @ [`ec9fcc1`/lib/npm.js#L254](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/ec9fcc1/lib/npm.js#L254) with:

```
path.resolve(process.execPath, '..', '..')
```

See also [`ec9fcc1`/lib/install.js#L521](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/ec9fcc1/lib/install.js#L521):

```
var globalPackage = path.resolve(npm.globalPrefix,
                                 'lib', 'node_modules', moduleName(pkg))
```

Where `globalPrefix` has a default set in [`ec9fcc1`/lib/config/defaults.js#L92-L105](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/ec9fcc1/lib/config/defaults.js#L92-L105) of:

```
if (process.env.PREFIX) {
    globalPrefix = process.env.PREFIX
} else if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    // c:\node\node.exe --> prefix=c:\node\
    globalPrefix = path.dirname(process.execPath)
} else {
    // /usr/local/bin/node --> prefix=/usr/local
    globalPrefix = path.dirname(path.dirname(process.execPath))

    // destdir only is respected on Unix
    if (process.env.DESTDIR) {
        globalPrefix = path.join(process.env.DESTDIR, globalPrefix)
    }
}
```

Comment: How should this work? For instance the Node binary is at `/usr/bin/node`, but obviously (since this is the bin) modules are not there; instead they are at `/usr/lib/node_modules`.

Comment: Updated with reference to `npm` implementation

Comment: Now this is a different story; you bring in the platform (good) and the respective env variables (despite not mentioning what important functions such as moduleName are doing, but I guess the average reader will be able to infer). Thanks for the modification / correction!

Answer (score 1):

Btw, npm will look for node_modules in parent folders (up to very root) if can not find in local.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio installed, you will find it comes with its own copy of node separate from the one that is on the path when you installed node yourself - Mine is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs.

If you run the npm command from inside this directory you will find out which node modules are installed inside visual studio.