# How to solve error message "Cannot find module 'abbrev'

Tags: ruby, node.js, gruntjs, frontend

My question is very similar to [How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/nodejs-how-to-resolve-cannot-find-module-error) but I cannot solve my problem using the information provided in the answer given.

I try to run the UNCSS grunt plugin, but when I try to install it (**npm install grunt-uncss --save-dev**), I get the following error:

```
$ npm install grunt-uncss --save-dev

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'abbrev'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.20/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:10:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Based on the answer mentioned above, I tried installing this 'abbrev' module, both in project folder, and globally, but this yields the exact same error :(

```
npm install -g abbrev

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'abbrev'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (modu
   (ETCETERA)
```

Main question: How to I solve this error?

Sub questions:
1) I wonder, is this a RUBY error or a NODE.JS error? I noticed 'abbrev' is also a Ruby command...? 
2) Or, could this problem have arisen because I tried to solve the *bus error: 10* ? (http://shoogledesigns.com/blog/blog/2014/01/13/gruntjs-running-watch-task-waiting-bus-error-10/)

I hope this question doesn't sound too obvious. I'm a front-end developer, but far from a command-line guru!

Comment: What is your question? Is it a ruby error on node.js? Or, how to solve that?

Comment: I specified the question, thanks. I want to solve the problem, but I'm also curious about the 'why'

Comment: please try `npm ls`in your project and add it.

Comment: Thanks,... it yields the same error as mentioned above! Ergo,... npm is broke...?

Comment: Have you tried npm cache clear?

Comment: Also that one resulted in the same error. I fixed the problem by re-installing node.js from their website. Apparently, fixing the bus: 10 error ruined my npm. (hypothesis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: re-installing node.js, as I mention in my last comment.

Tell-tale was the very same error-message every time I ran NPM.

Answer (score 3):

For me it has been solved by updating `npm` itself:

```
 sudo npm install -g npm
```

Comment: I was skeptical, but yes, this fixed my problem. At least try it out before anything else!

Answer (score 1):

Removing `node_modules` and then reinstalling the modules specified in my `package.json` worked for me.

I did that by runnning the following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: It should be "rm -rf node_modules"

Answer (score 0):

Neither one of the other two answers solved it for me, but both together did.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. Removing the entire `node_modules` folder and re-installing it's worked for me. I did that by running the following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

**Windows user here.** I tried re-installing Node.js (using installer) and it did not help. I had to run the `rm -rf node_modules` to remove the "node_modules" folder at the location listed in the error (midway down).

In the OP example it was at 
Object. (**/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.20/lib/node_modules/**

It was something like C:\Users\nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules