# Cannot find module 'jspm'

Tags: node.js, jspm

Any ideas about the following errors?

```
   C:\PGM\_CODE\zui>npm install -g jspm
    C:\PGM\devel\node-v7.2.1-win-x64\jspm -> C:\PGM\devel\node-v7.2.1-win-x64\node_m
    odules\jspm\jspm.js
    C:\PGM\devel\node-v7.2.1-win-x64
    `-- jspm@0.16.53



C:\PGM\_CODE\zui>gulp watch
Index generation: 83.257ms
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'jspm'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\PGM\_CODE\zui\build\tasks\export-release.js:7:14)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446384/gulp-command-giving-errors-of-modules-can-not-find

Comment: It worked when I hard-coded the path to the module. Obviously this isn't the right way to do it :( ... `const jspm = require('/PGM/devel/node-v7.2.1-win-x64/node_modules/jspm/jspm.js');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, funny enough I had this problem in 2017 and ran into it again in 2019.

### In 2019

So this time, in order to fix it: I removed the JS extension, and set a new node_modules path.

So in the command prompt I run:

```
SET NODE_PATH=D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

And I changed the command to be:

```
const jspm = require('jspm');
```

### Previously, in 2017

I had hardcoded the path to the JS file.
Obviously this isn't the right way to do it but I am mentioning it in case the other does not work.

```
const jspm = require('/PGM/devel/node-v7.2.1-win-x64/node_modules/jspm/jspm.js');
```