# Not able to run ionic add platform os

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I've a problem with ionic android running. When start the running 'ionic add platform os' showing me an error. I am running in windows. But not able resolve this. kindly help me to solve this issue. i have tried 'npm install -g cordova, npm install -g ionic' but still this issue comes. is there any restrictions that eclipse should not run. or any other problem.

```
ionic add platform os
module.js:339
    throw err;
Error: Cannot find module 'cordova-common'
     (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\plugman.js:22:14)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

Comment: ionic add platform os or ios?

Comment: dear, i tried both ionic add platform ios/android but not working.. i feel that would be any permission or installation pbm. have u faced this kind of error..

Comment: for the ios you have to use sudo before any command. For example sudo ionic platform add android / ios

Comment: Hi. firstly i m running in windows . 'ionic add platform android' not working. above error comes. Path also i set in environmental variable. what else the solutions can be..

Comment: http://mywebsolutions.blogspot.in/2013/03/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-android.html. check this link

Comment: May i know what tool or IDE you use for ionic+angular. i m beginner. can suggest correct IDE for ionic development.. i saw 3 ways. 1. eclipse 2. visual studio 3. cmd prompt.

Comment: Personally i use sublime text editor + cmd prompt

Comment: thank u so much @paresh and all. i do and tell ..

Comment: @Jambu. tell me anything else i can help you

Comment: whats that 'ionic bundle' in E:\ionic bundle\bundle\adt-bundle-windows\sdk. is there sdk avail to download.

Comment: Did u set the android tools and build tool on environment variable in your system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/nodejs-how-to-resolve-cannot-find-module-error

Answer (score 0):

Path setting for windows...

```
User Variable
ANDROID_HOME
E:\ionic bundle\bundle\adt-bundle-windows\sdk
----
Environment Variable
PATH
E:\ionic bundle\bundle\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\platform-tools;
E:\ionic bundle\bundle\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;
```

Change above path as per your sdk setting