# Cannot Find Module Angular2 Ctrl

Tags: angular

This is a popular question with several resources on the web to resolve. However after trying multiple solutions none have worked. I am getting an error which says  **Cannot Find Module './neuralnet'.**

[image: Typescript Ctrl]

[image: File Paths]

I have tried some of the solutions listed here

[How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js)

including npm install and npm install --save neuralnet and nothing has worked.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it setup -- in home.component.ts -- your `import { NeuralNetService } from './neuralnet.service'`, is looking in the current directory, which is in `app/components/home`. This clearly isn't where it is.

Use `import { NeuralNetService } from './../../neuralnet.service'` and it will properly resolve.

Comment: (stepped out for lunch).. yeah hard to tell the directories sometimes when you can't click around, glad it worked out for you :)