# Angular cli error: Cannot find module 'ejs'

Tags: typescript, angular5

I keep getting "cannot find module 'ejs'" whenever run ng-serve from the angular-cli.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js)

Comment: @AnikoLitvanyi i've done npm uninstall, npm install. i still can't get my app running.