# I just removed node_modules, how do I reinstall them all?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm

Initially I was just trying to run a demo app to practice mongoose.  The app, cats.js, would not run with node because I would get this error:

```
module.js:540
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './timestamp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/taylorlassiter/Desktop/visual_studio/yelp_camp/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/bson.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

Unfortunately, the ./timestamp module appeared in all the places listed in the error.

I read [How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js) to try to fix it and ended up running "rm -rf node_modules" which removed all node_modules.  When I tried to reinstall with "npm install", I get these errors:

```
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.12.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I haven't seen any answers regarding these two errors.

My first priority is getting npm reinstalled.  My second priority would be to figure out the original error I was receiving when trying to run cats.js, but I can create a new question for that.

Comment: If you still have the node json config that lists all your dependencies - just do npm install -save in the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you have a module that depends on another as a peer dependency. Peer dependencies were created to solve a problem with plugins. Have a look at these posts for more information; [npm peer dependecies](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) and [understanding the npm dependecy model](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2016/08/24/understanding-the-npm-dependency-model/)

If you have ran `npm install` and got this error it seems that you don't have `jquery@1.9.1` and `popper.js@^1.12.9` installed and saved to you package.json

To get rid of this you should manually install them first, then run `npm install` again. Try this;

```
rm -r node_modules
npm install jquery@1.9.1 --save
npm install popper.js@^1.12.9 --save
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

During previous installation of your 
`node_modules`, if the save flag was enabled then all those modules must be having an entry in your `package.json`'s `dependencies` object.

In that case just do `npm i` short for `npm install`and every module that you earlier had will get reinstalled.

If there isn't anything in your `package.json`'s `dependencies` object, then you need to install each of your module again by specifying the module name and this time don't forget to mention the `--save` flag.

Just start doing `npm i dep-1 dep-2 ... --save`.

If you find writing `--save` a little exhausting then just do this once in your repository.

```
npm config set save=true
```

This will enable save flag for each dependency you will install here onwards.