# classNames is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am newbie in react development and trying to understand how classNames work in react.

This is the react code from my book. I just copied it.

```
const MOUNT = document.getElementById('root');
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const klasses = classNames({
      box: true, // always apply the box class
      alert: this.props.isAlert, // if the prop is set
      severity: this.state.onHighAlert, // with state
      timed: false // never apply this class
    });
    return React.createElement(
      'div',
      {className: klasses},
      React.createElement('h1', {}, 'Hello world')
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, {}), MOUNT);
```

I included script file with this code to html and browser console shows such error.

```
app.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: classNames is not defined
at App.render (app.js:4)
at finishClassComponent (react-dom.js:11320)
at updateClassComponent (react-dom.js:11297)
at beginWork (react-dom.js:11676)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.js:13644)
at workLoop (react-dom.js:13753)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.js:1527)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.js:1566)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.js:1423)
at performWork (react-dom.js:13871)
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Where are you defining `classNames` ?

Comment: @Derek I don't know. As I said this code is not mine. Just copied it. Probably it is not defined. I am reading e-book and downloaded all their source code. This is only one js code which I found on this chapter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I think you'll want to install the classnames npm module to bind conditional classes defined in an object.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

```
npm i classnames --save
```

Next you'll want to require that in your .js / .jsx file before use.

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
```

Then use the module to bind your classes to the React Element.

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
const MOUNT = document.getElementById('root');
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const klasses = classNames({
        box: true, // always apply the box class
        alert: this.props.isAlert, // if the prop is set
        severity: this.state.onHighAlert, // with state
        timed: false // never apply this class
    });
    return React.createElement(
      'div',
      {className: klasses},
      React.createElement('h1', {}, 'Hello world')
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, {}), MOUNT);
```

Hope this helps, looks like Tholle got there first.

Comment: do you know difference between npm i classnames --save and npm i -S classnames? I tried both and I don't see any difference

Comment: They're the exact same statement! -S is just shorthand for --save, the same way npm i is just shorthand for npm install

Comment: Thanks. I tried the console command and added import on the top of my app.js file. but my chrome 67 browser shows Uncaught Syntaxerror..

Comment: Should I do npm install before npm install -S classnames?

Comment: are you using babel to transpile your js files from es6 to es5? if not use change the import statement to:
var classNames = require("classnames")

LMK if this outputs any errors to your console

Comment: added type=text/babel to my script. Thanks. Error is disappeared!

Comment: The actual code for the chapter didn't even include a package.json. So probably best to do an npm init -y first before the npm i classnames -S

Answer (score 5):

[classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) is a library that you need to install and import into your module. Try `npm i -S classnames` in your shell, and then `import classNames from 'classnames';` at the top of your JavaScript file.

Comment: In my react experiences - react/gatsby for react/react native - i've never had to import classNames...

Comment: @StephenTetreault well its not native to react so I'm not sure what you're using that bundles it with it

Comment: I did npm i -S classnames. The name of the js file is app.js. I added import on the top of the app.js and my browser shows unexpected identifier.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above work but you need change the line that imports `app.js` in your `index.html` file:

`<script type="module" "src="app.js"></script>`

The suggestions above worked for me (I am reading the same React book as your).

Comment: Good solution. But you run into CORS roadblock when told to use file protocol. Per the instructions. And on a Mac you have to preface all the scripts with . to be found. Code sucks in that chapter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 0):

1. Per the comment from @kust kust
   you need to add `type="text/babel"` to the `<script>` tag for `app.js`.
2. You need to update all paths to be relative ... from `/` to `./`