# Webpack-dev-server Error: Cannot find module , can't understand why?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a new project and setup webpack to use as a module bundler but when I start the webpack-dev-server using **npm start** script , I got an error

```
Error can't find module : 
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

although I wrote everything correct and I don't get the point of why this happened ? can any one tell me why this happen ?

this is my **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "simple-webpack-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webapck.common.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

and this is my **webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin') ;
module.exports = {
    entry:{
        index:'./src/index.js',
        app:'./src/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test :/\.css$/,
                use:['style-loader','css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
          {
              chunks:['app'],
              template:'./index.html'
          }
      )
    ],
    devServer: {
        port:4000
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js)

Answer (score 3):

I tried your project setup in my IDE and I think I found the solution of your problem , I think you wrote the wrong config name in **package.json** file

your file in the disk called **webpack.common.js**

the file name in package.json **webapck.common.js**

so to solve the problem

change the file name in package.json to **webpack.common.js** instead of **webapck.common.js** this will solve the problem I think , change the package.json **start** script to

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.common.js"
```

Comment: thank you , that's solve the problem , I really stuck with it