# Issue with starting a new project in angular

Tags: angular

I installed angular 6 on my system and was trying to start a new project using command ng new project_1, but it was returning this error "cannot find module uri-js".
Tried using angular 7 but same error comes. Anyone can give a solution please?

Comment: If you type this  `ng -v` into your terminal what do you see

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9023672/4400533) post! hope this helps

Comment: ng --version gives Angular cli : 7.1.2, followed by package lists

Comment: try after cleaning cache `npm cache clean -f`

Comment: angular app name rules, there can only be a letter after '-', like project-one. you can not use project-2 as the project name.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try install it using npm? `npm install uri-js`

Comment: I tried it, but same error. Should I install uri in some specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the package might help,

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
If you are using npm>5 you may need to use cache verify instead. (npm cache verify)
```

use sudo before above commands if you are using Linux eg (sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli)

Answer (score 0):

Angular app name rules, there can only be a letter after '-', like project-one. you can not use project-1 as the project name.

After that u have to use this cli command:-

```
    npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
    npm cache clean or npm cache clean -f
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    ng new project-one
```