# nodejs crypto library in Ionic 4

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am currently developing an Ionic 4 application and need to asymmetrically encrypt a small text string, I would like to use `nodejs`'s `crypto` library to call `crypto.privateDecrypt` and `crypto.publicEncrypt`.

I have tried importing the crypto library to my Ionic application by adding the following to the top of my file: `import * as crypto from 'crypto';` which half does the job. But as soon as I try to run the application on my Android phone I get the following error, `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'crypto'`

Does anyone know how to correctly include the crypto library in Ionic 4? I assume it is just not copying across to my device as the IntelliSense works perfectly and is picking up all the methods.

Comment: did you try to explicitly call it?? like this `import { crypto } from 'crypto'` ??

Comment: I tried that as well, keep getting the error `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'crypto'`

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js

Comment: Tried that, no luck unfortunately.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Souleste - I think I ended up using the web crypto API. `window.crypto.*` you can have a look at this repo which might help: https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/