# Why is the variable route path not working in Express.js and giving out an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this little Express.js calculator, that is supposed to pass variable routes depending on types of operation and operands are passed as variables too. However, an error is given.

```
var express = require("express");

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var app = express();

let operation; let operand1; let operand2;

app.get(`/:operation/:operand1/:operand2`, function(req, res) {

  var result;

  switch (operation) {

  case "add":
    result=operand1+operand2;
    break;
  case "subtract":
    result=operand1-operand2;
    break;
  case "multiply":
    result=operand1*operand2;
    break;
  case "divide":
    result=operand1/operand2;
    break;
  default:
    result="Sorry! The only valid operations are add, subtract, multiply, and divide.";
  }


  res.send(result.toString());

});


app.listen(PORT, function() {

  console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:" + PORT);
});
```

The error given by Node.js is

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\19513\Desktop\In-Class-Exercises\calculator.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Comment: Where are you trying to import calculator.js?

Comment: Why would I import it? It's in switch statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js  Because that error is usually a problem with import paths or node modules.  The error indicates a missing local module.