# Cannot find module 'yargs' error while deploying node.js app to google cloud platform

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, yargs

I am trying to deploy my node.js application to `google cloud` and my package.json includes the `yargs` as dependencies.

And when I deploy the app to google cloud and after that I am getting error **can't find module yargs** in google cloud platform logs.

How can I solve the above issue?

Answer (score 9):

i had this problem too. all you need to do is installing 'yargs' locally by

```
npm init
npm i yargs --save
```

you can see the complete guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

While installing the **yargs** module, I encountered similar errors. I noticed that the `type:module` property was present in my "package.json" file. Removing this property resolved the issue, and my code started working as expected

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
nvm install v18.12.0
nvm use v18.12.0
```

This will solve yargs error.