# How to solve npm start issue?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-start

I have get the following error:

[image]

It works on Linux, but does not work o Windows.

What dependency I should install? I can not find Color npm dependecy

Comment: Where did you import utilities/color ? Show us some code

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js

Comment: I dont import it,

Comment: I have tried clear cache force and reinstall, no effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js)

Comment: I have checked this answer, no effect

Comment: check with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do NPM cache clean and install again