# How I i solve Build Failed on Azure Devops Pipeline when building a node application

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have been studying azure devops in the past weeek and i have been trying to deoploy my first node app on azure but i keep running on an error of build failed. and the error is 
**Error Cannot find module './routes/hostelRoutes'** so i have checked and confirmed that the module is available because everything runs on my local machine. Below is a pic where i get the error

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message：

> Error Cannot find module './routes/hostelRoutes'

The ‘node_modules’ folder could have some issues.

You could try to remove the directory ‘/node_modules/’ and re-install the folder.

Please refer to the following command line script about removing and re-installing.

```
cd  Project_folder
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

You could check this ticket [How do I resolve “Cannot find module” error using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js/30436256#30436256) for some information

Comment: Tahnks soo mucn. Acutally i realized there was a problem with my git history . the file had a conflitct before so it was not being tracked