# Error: Cannot find module 'jose' in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jose

I installed the module. Only this module is not working other modules are working fine. When I trying to run it it's throwing following error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jose'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<my_folder>\test.js:1:100)     
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)   
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

What I tried:

Almost everything from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js)

1. Removed node modules folder and installed again
2. Cleared cache and installed again
3. Installed `npm install @types/node --save-dev`

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "axios-retry": "^3.1.9",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "qs": "^6.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.10",
    "jose": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you require your jose modules?

Comment: If everything is done correctly but still getting error --make sure you've node.js version > 12.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jose` package exports individual ESM modules, as in, there's no root `jose` module in version 3.x that you're installing. You can read how to require/import each individual module in the project's [documentation](https://github.com/panva/jose/tree/v3.x/docs)

Answer (score 1):

Update your NodeJS runtime. Fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem on react as follows

```
import { jwtVerify } from 'jose/dist/browser/jwt/verify'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nuxt you can resolve this error by adding the types into the build transpile option in `nuxt.config.js` like so:

```js
 build: {
        transpile: ['@jose/dist/types']
    },
```

After this I am able to import everything from Jose like so:

```js
import {jwtVerify, importSPKI} from "jose";
```

Doing it like this gives you full type descriptions and everything!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use `npm install --save-dev jose` to install jose :D

Comment: that's the first thing I done. thanks for the info :D

Comment: Not sure to understand... Is the `Installed npm install @types/node --save-dev` just a typo by copy/paste and you are ironic? Or did you did this mistake and you're are happy to realize it? I'm confuse. And the second case, give a link to the github to see package.json and so...

Comment: I updated my package.json file please check.thanks

Comment: Ok not helping, if you have a github with the project, maybe it can be fixed quickly