# how do i solve this error while running javascript in my node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to run my script "script.js" on node.js use command "node script.js"
but i got this error

```
  node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\script.js'
    [90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)[39m
    [90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)[39m
    [90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)[39m
    [90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47[39m {
      code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
      requireStack: []
    }
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: Is the location where the script.js file is located 'C:\Users\User\script.js'?

Comment: Please refer to this document. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js

Comment: yes it is, been trying to move it to other partition or creating new folder not work either

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you are running the node command in the same folder that the `script.js` file exist. If you are opening command prompt from a different location and try running `node script.js`, an error will be thrown as

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\yourpath\script.js' [90m    at
> Function.Module._resolveFilename
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)[39m [90m    at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)[39m
> [90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
> (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)[39m [90m    at
> internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m {   code:
> [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,   requireStack: [] }

This indicates that the file doesnot exist in the desired path.

As per your question, you are running the command from `C:\Users\User`, so your `script.js` file must be there at the location `C:\Users\User\script.js`. If your script.js is at some other location, say `C:\Users\yourusername\somerandomfolderpath`, then you have to open your command prompt at that folder **or** go to that location using command prompt using these commads.

```
C:
cd C:\Users\yourusername\somerandomfolderpath
```

The first command takes you to the required drive (expecting it to be C drive here). The second command takes to the required folder in that drive.

After this you can run your script using.

```
node script.js
```

Comment: i run them from the same folder either "node script.js" or "node C:\Users\User\script.js" not work. been trying reinstall through cmd and windows program not work either.

Comment: @isfanafely ist not the issue with windows. Its just the issue with our usage of command.

Comment: i saw thread the ubuntu user solve this issu by reinstall it so i tried them