# I have an error "Error: Cannot find module" in a Node terminal program

Tags: node.js

I have this error:

```
Last login: Thu Dec 23 12:32:55 on ttys000
juliedecraene@Julies-MBP ~ % node -- version
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/juliedecraene/version'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Node.js v17.3.0

From `npm -- version` I get:

```
{
  npm: '8.3.0',
  node: '17.3.0',
  v8: '9.6.180.15-node.12',
  uv: '1.42.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.18.1',
  modules: '102',
  nghttp2: '1.45.1',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.4',
  openssl: '3.0.1+quic',
  cldr: '40.0',
  icu: '70.1',
  tz: '2021a3',
  unicode: '14.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
  nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to figure out what went wrong with just that information but a quick troubleshoot can be checking the following:

1. Make sure you executed `npm install` at the root path of your project.
2. You have a `package.json` and `package-lock.json` at the root of your project along with the main file (commonly `app.js`) These files are created by using the `npm install` command in your terminal.
3. You are executing `npm` commands at the root of your project (where `app.js` and the `package` files are).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js) might also be helpful.