# npx create-react-app aps shows error node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5aOH.png)npx create-react-app app shows error that seen in the image

my error is
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'ini'

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause for this error could be because you're trying to create a React app in `E` drive when `npm` is installed in `C` drive.

Try running `npx create-react-app app` in a `C` drive location.

Here's [another helpful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js) on the same topic if the above solution doesn't work.