# Error while installing ssh2-sftp-client in Next.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, ssh, sftp, yarnpkg

I want to store uploaded files in my domains storage through SFTP. So I found multer-sftp package but when I tried to run the command `yarn add multer-sftp ssh2-sftp-client` the second package gives a weired error. I tried removing and reinstalling node_modules, installing cmake in wsl then reinstall packages as in [How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top), but neither of them worked for me.
I'am working on WSL environment, and using nvm with node version `16.14.0`.
Please is there a solution or another package to solve my issues.
The error I got :

```bash
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: ".../node_modules/cpu-features: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node buildcheck.js > buildcheck.gypi && node-gyp rebuild
Arguments: 
Directory: .../node_modules/cpu-features
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
gyp info using node@16.14.2 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at \"/usr/bin/python3\"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/home/senku/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '..../node_modules/cpu-features/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/senku/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/senku/.cache/node-gyp/16.14.2/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/senku/.cache/node-gyp/16.14.2',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/senku/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/senku/.cache/node-gyp/16.14.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/senku/hotel-pms/node_modules/cpu-features',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/senku/hotel-pms/node_modules/cpu-features/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_aarch64_linux_or_android.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_arm_linux_or_android.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_mips_linux_or_android.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_ppc_linux.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_x86_freebsd.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_x86_linux_or_android.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_x86_macos.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_x86_windows.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/filesystem.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/stack_line_reader.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/string_view.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/cpu_features/cpu_features.a
  COPY Release/cpu_features.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cpufeatures/src/binding.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [cpufeatures.target.mk:124: Release/obj.target/cpufeatures/src/binding.o] Error 127
gyp ERR!make: Leaving directory '/home/senku/hotel-pms/node_modules/cpu-features/build'
 build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/senku/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
gyp ERR! command \"/home/senku/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node\" \"/home/senku/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/senku/hotel-pms/node_modules/cpu-features
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to install g++ on your machine (and maybe other dependencies in the further process), as the error message states:

*make: g++: Command not found*