# React Script start

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-scripts

When ever I run the script npm start I get this error, I deleted the nodemodule folder and package-lock.json and re install again, yet I am still getting the error ,
I have updated my nodejs to latest version And cleared my npm cache still no progress, please help.

I can't start the development server

react-scripts start

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:446
      throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\El-kufahn\Documents\CORSERA REACT\portfolio\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\finalhandler\node_modules\debug\src\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry


    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:438:19)


    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:680:18)


    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063:27)


    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)


    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)


    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)


    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\El-kufahn\Documents\CORSERA REACT\portfolio\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js:14:13)


    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)


    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)


    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32) {


  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',


  path: 'C:\\Users\\El-kufahn\\Documents\\CORSERA REACT\\portfolio\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\node_modules\\finalhandler\\node_modules\\debug\\package.json',

  requestPath: 'debug'
}
```

Node.js v18.17.0

Answer (score 0):

Add type module to your `package.json` file. If you are getting same error again then add your `package.json` file in question.

[image: See this image]

Comment: You can also checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js