How to resolve model not found error while running a node file
C:\Users\Esther\Desktop\app-project\DeliveryDashboard>node main.js 
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148  
  throw err;
  ^  
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Esther\Desktop\app-project\DeliveryDashboard\main.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.14.0
I've tried installing npm, express and hbs but still end up with the same error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js

Does this answer your question? How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js?

So, did you expect there to be a file at C:\Users\Esther\Desktop\app-project\DeliveryDashboard\main.js? I don't see what this has to do with npm or installing dependencies.
