# node.js and node-postgres syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I just installed node-postgres by running npm install pg .

In my source code, I added `var pg = require('pg");` 
and when I run I now get

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'pg'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rrazavipour-lp/Documents/workspace/Astute/app.js:9:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:497:10)
```

What step am I missing?

Comment: This might help...   ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
express  npm  pg  prettyjson soap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the node_modules folder in relation to your application?

from http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html:

If the module identifier passed to require() is not a native module, and does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then node starts at the parent directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and attempts to load the module from that location.

Comment: then either copy it to the same directory your code is running from or run npm install from the directory your code is running from.

Comment: should I not be doing : npm install pg -g for global? Or when do you use -g?

Comment: it is recommended to install locally unless you need a binary to your $path variable see http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/ if you want to install it globally see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package