# nodejs - can't find module Backbone

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, npm

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
```

causes this error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'backbone'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\denman\workspace-nodejs\AFirstServer_NodeUpAndRunning\hello-world-server.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

how can this be?

I installed Backbone via `npm install -g backbone`

I even restarted Eclipse and my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, node will not load modules that are installed globally. You should be performing any `npm install`-s in your project's directory root, not installing them globally.

Try this instead. Create your new project directory, change to it, and then:

```
npm init  #this will create a package.json for your project
npm install --save backbone  # this will install backbone to the directory, and save it into your package.json as a dependency
```

Then create a file in that directory called `index.js`. Put your code in there requiring backbone. Then from within that directory run `node index.js`, and you'll find that everything works, and backbone is available.

Here is a [good blog post on the subject](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/).

Comment: hmmm then how come express worked when I installed it globally, makes no sense?

Comment: I did get a warning that there was "no repository field" when I ran "npm install --save backbone"...my package.json file doesn't have that field defined..."repository": ""

Comment: npm will warn when there's no repository field in your package.json, but it will not cause any problems. You can [read here](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html) about the package.json fields that are available, and what each expects.

Comment: as to why Express works; did you `npm link express` in your local folder? technically it should not work unless you did. Here is another [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package) on the subject.