# why I cannot use socket.io module if install globally

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I just want to ask why I cannot use the module of socket.io if I install this globally, I am new in socket.io, I tried to execute this command "npm install socket.io" to this C:\Users\username>npm install socket.io
but then after It installed and run my app.js.I get error cannot find socket.io module..but when I run command "npm install socket.io" where my app.js is located it works fine.

I have this version of node.js
**v0.12.0**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean "npm install socket.io"?

Comment: sorry for that it should npm,I will update my post

Comment: possible duplicate of [NodeJS require a global module/package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package)

Comment: On windows, this is usually because some environment variable that is supposed to point at the global repository is not set correctly.

Comment: @frined00, so it should be install where my app.js resides

Comment: @jfriend00,how to set this correctly the path can you help me please

Comment: I don't know.  You'll have to do some research on settings up NPM on windows.  It should all be documented somewhere.

Comment: @jfriend00, I set now to the windows environment varialbe like this---> ;C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\   but it doesn't work