# Multer module won't start

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, multer

I'm writing a web app using the MEAN stack. I installed multer via npm like so:

```
sudo npm install -g multer
```

and I require it in one of my routes files:

```
var multer = require("multer");
```

I'm using `nodemon` and it throws the following error every time it restarts since I've added the require statement.

```
28 Feb 18:39:13 - [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
28 Feb 18:39:13 - [nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'multer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jason/Desktop/Node/todoApp/routes/todos.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
28 Feb 18:39:13 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've installed mongo, node, and express all in the past two days. I'm running OS X Yosemite version 10.10.2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to install the module locally, without the `-g` flag:

```
$ npm i multer
```

Alternatively, you can either link the globally installed module to local directory or specify an environment variable `NODE_PATH` as illustrated in [NodeJS require a global module/package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package)

Answer (score 4):

If using typescript don't forget to install it's types

```
npm install @types/multer
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error `Error: Cannot find module 'multer'` and I solved it by running the command

```
npm install multer
```

which installed the multer module and when I ran the

```
npm start
```

command, my project was successfully executed and displayed in the browser.