# behavior differs for npm install and npm install -g

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

In order to build frontend sources on **Windows 7** with **gulp.js** I have a `package.json` file with `node_modules` dependencies defined in it:

```
{
  "name": "custom-repo-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-rev": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

For some reason when I run

`npm install`

the dependencies are installed locally into `.\node_modules` folder and `gulp` command runs properly.

But when I run

`npm install -g`,

as I can see from the output, a part of dependencies is missing to be installed and running `gulp` command fails with an error of failed load of dependencies (gulp-uglify.js for instance).

What's wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to use -g in this case? doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @KevinB shame on me, I missed to tell the background.

The problem is really that I can't afford a TeamCity agent to install all npm dependencies **locally** everytime it runs a build. It will take too much time, because the working folder location is dynamic and then i'll have to dynamically install npm dependencies on and on.

So the idea is to have all the dependencies installed globally and just run `gulp` from the working folder when TC has to build a project.

Comment: you can't `require` globally installed modules, so i don't think that's going to help you much.

Comment: You can set your [`NODE_PATH`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) variable to point to the location where your globally installed modules are. [Beware though...](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/586)

Comment: @KevinB well, it sounds strange to me, but explains much. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @laggingreflex already set, but it doesn't make an effect for some reason

Comment: @KevinB where can I read more about this behavior?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package