# Git bash though error while run npm packages

Tags: node.js, git, bash, ionic-framework, npm

While I am running any project in my git bash it's showing the following error:

```
ionic -v
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

So I am not able to run the project and also it create a `sh.exe.stackdump` file in my project. I am not sure what the problem is. Please anyone help to find out the solution.

Comment: run `npm ionic -v`, if it shows nothing  did your try `npm install ionic`

Comment: when i run npm ionic -v it show ionic version but when i try to run it show the error that i mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

After cloning a repo you should run :

> npm install

in your git root folder to install npm dependencies before being able to run the app.

Comment: Yeah i do this but the same problem occurs.

Comment: npm install
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ch       okidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@       1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"       })

Comment: Does the folder 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic' exists on your machine ?

Comment: no if i install ionic globally it saved inside my user/appdata/roaming/npm  my git folder does not contain ionic

Comment: Then you should add the folder where ionic is installed to your NODE_PATH env variable. You can find out some more on this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package