# d3.scaleSequential is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, command-line-interface, cartography

Following Mike Bostock's [great tutorial on command-line cartography](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-4-82d0d26df0cf), when trying to produce a choropleth, I receive a TypeError saying that `d3.scaleSequential` is not a function. I imagine it is just not being exposed? But I don't know how to deal with that through the CLI...?

Error Traceback:

```
TypeError: d3.scaleSequential is not a function
    at evalmachine.:1:26
    at Interface. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndjson-cli/ndjson-map:45:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at Interface. (readline.js:340:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Interface._normalWrite (readline.js:339:11)
    at ReadStream.ondata (readline.js:86:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
```

I have all of the needed libraries installed and updated through npm, so that isn't the issue..any thoughts on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Currently Installed:

- d3@4.9.1
- d3-geo-projection@2.1.2
- d3-scale@1.0.6
- d3-scale-chromatic@1.1.1

### Sample Code

The code is copied pretty much straight from [the tutorial](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-2-c3a82c5c0f3) and this is the first step that doesn't work..

```
ndjson-map -r d3 \
  '(d.properties.fill = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis).domain([0, 4000])(d.properties.density), d)' \
   ca-albers-color.ndjson
```

Comment: What version of D3 are you using?

Comment: I had a similar error when I tried to shift from the full d3.v4 to the individual libraries (d3.scaleOrdinal was the one I was missing). I haven't got round to troubleshooting it yet, but I'll be back if I figure it out.

Comment: I think you need to install the scale functions separately - `npm install -g d3-scale`

Comment: @madebydavid `d3.scaleSequential()` is part of the default bundle.

Comment: @madebydavid Just updated with versions...oops

Comment: Can you add some code to show how it's being called?

Comment: @anbnyc Added the sample code.

Comment: I'd try changing it temporarily to a different type of scale to make sure that `d3` is loaded correctly. At least then you can rule that out...it looks like you're calling the function correctly, though I think you need a `>` in front of the file name on the next line.

Comment: @anbnyc It appears that's the issue. I changed it to another scale and see the same missing function TypeError. Is there a reason `-r d3` wouldn't work?

Comment: I think it's related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package. Workaround is to just `npm install` in the local folder.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the CLI, `d3` needs to be accessible to node.js, so you should `npm install -g d3` (global), or in the directory from which you're running the command line scripts, `npm install d3`.

UPDATE: If you use the global approach, you may need to link the package (https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) or set your `NODE_PATH` variable to have access to the folder where global modules are installed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. When I installed them, they were installed globally with `npm install -g d3`