# Nodejs - Cant import module unless use the full path

Tags: node.js, npm, web3js

I installed it and am trying to use the w3 module (on windows).

I have altered my global repo location to: `C:\Users\<user>\.node_modules_global`
and installed the web3 module with the command bellow, which created a new folder on the node_modules_global folder:

```
npm install ethereum/web3.js --global
```

When I try to run:

`Web3 = require('web3')` it, I get an

`Error: Cannot find module 'web3'`

however, if I use the fullpath:

```
Web3 = require('C:\\Users\\<user>\\.node_modules_global\\node_modules\\web3')
```

It works.

Any idea what could be causing this issue? (I have added `C:\\Users\\<user>\\.node_modules_global` to the SYSTEM PATH).

Comment: What is your node_modules env path set to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs cannot find installed module on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows)

Comment: You need to install locally, not globally ;) Just remove the `-g` flag

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your installing it globally, so it is saved to your user folder, rather than in the project, and node is configured by default to look in `node_modules`.

Two options to fix this:

- (a) **Save Packages Locally Instead**

  - Use just `npm install ethereum/web3.js` or `npm install ethereum/web3.js --save` to install it to the `node_modules` directory within your project. (You must have cd'd into your project folder first!)
- (b) **Make Node look in your global folders by default**

  - use `"NODE_PATH": "C:\\Users\\<user>\\.node_modules_global\\node_modules"`

### How to install locally, and how to install globally

- To locally install a module, just do `npm install my-module`, or if you'd also like to add it to your package.json, then do `npm install my-module --save`
- To Globally install a module, use `npm install my-module --global`

### When to use local and global modules

You should:

- Install a module locally if you're going to require() it.
- Install a module globally if you're going to run it on the command line.

Source: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/

### Changing Node path

You can set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable to your own value, and your application will by default look there, instead of the projects `node_modules` directory.

See here: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

Comment: interesting - I was tryin to avoid local install if I knew I'd be using the same package more than once. What you said seems to have worked, Im just getting a message: npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\git\Crypto\samples\eth1\package.json'  should I worry about that? thanks

Comment: That warning can be fixed by creating a package.json, try ruinning `npm init` and it will make one for you :) It's just a warning, not an error so not too much of a big deal. `package.json` is used to keep track of all your dependencies, see here: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json