# Puppeteer : JS files only work when placed inside puppeteer directory of node modules

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 running on my system where I installed Puppeteer with the following command :

```
sudo npm install -g puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true
```

As I can see, the module is installed correctly at `/usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/`.

Now, if I add a file, `example.js` inside the above mentioned directory and run it with `node example.js`, I get the correct results, but if the file is placed anywhere else, puppeteer is not found.

Have I missed something, should I add something in the PATH? I want to access puppeteer globally. Thank you.

I checked the question suggested by the user, already have a NODE_PATH pointing to `/usr/lib/node_modules`. Even tried `npm link puppeteer`, didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS require a global module/package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package)

Comment: Edited main post to reflect changes tried, which didn't work. Thank you.