# NodeJS Error: Cannot find module 'moment'

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, momentjs, global

I have installed the module momentjs globally as follows:

```
sudo npm install -g moment
```

Unfortunately I can't load it:

```
> var moment = require('moment');
```

> Error: Cannot find module 'moment'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)

If I install it with the `--save` flag it works, but I want to have it globally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS require a global module/package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package)