# Node.js can't find module ibm_db

Tags: node.js

Sorry for yet another nube question but I haven't touched JS in years..

I'm confused with node.js, `npm ls -g --depth 0` clearly shows `ibm_db` listed and yet a

```
var ibmdb = require('ibm_db')
```

from within a node cli,
errors with can't find module `ibm_db`.

Netbeans search found the Node.js files without issue..

I know it's going to be something annoyingly obvious, but just can't see it.

OS is ubuntu server..
I've tried 3 install commands:
As User-

```
npm install ibm_db
npm install -g ibm_db
```

As root-
    npm install -g ibm_db

`DB2CLI` is working correctly.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: how did you installed the module?

Comment: Looks like you wan't to *require globally* installed modules. This is not supported out of the box. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package

Comment: Thanks Guy's that worked :)