# In nodejs is there a way to have a module always available to me?

Tags: node.js, require, requestify

Like essentially a "global node_modules" or something similar,
so when I run node by itself,
I can always get, say the requestify package.

```
C:\> node
> var request=require('requestify');
```

Without "being in" a folder that already has requestify loaded into node_modules in that very same directory (ie, so I dont have to pepper every folder with a node_modules with requestify in it)

Comment: Just realized this is a Possible duplicate of [NodeJS require a global module/package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package)

Answer (score 1):

Try npm install with the -g flag.

Comment: That doesnt work.  Went to a folder without a node_modules, ran `npm install request -g` then typed `node` and then `var a = require("request")` and that failed, so clearly global node_modules isn't included in the search pattern