# Why a module installed with "npm install -g themodule" doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I'm working on a Windows environment.

I install a module with

```
npm install -g themodule
```

The module is installed, I can see it with the command

```
npm list -g --depth 0
```

But when I do a require("themodule"), I get an the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'themodule'
```

I assume it's a rookie mistake but I don't see it.

Did someone have an explanation?

Comment: On your terminal, if you type `themodule`, is it recognized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS require a global module/package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package)

Comment: No duplication, I'm sure.

Comment: When I type themodule I get not error saying themodule isn't a command. I guess it's something with variable environment, I'm on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You are globally installing the package but not making it available in your node_modules folder for your project..

you need to give

`npm i --save-dev themodule`   // this installs a devDependency for development purpose

`npm i --save themodule`  // this installs a dependency and is for production ready.

(please see.. `npm i` is equivalent for `npm install`)

--

in short.. `devDependencies` object in `package.json` will have all the **development** related packages and `dependency` object will have **production** ready packages..

So.. to summon this.. when you say `require('themodule')`, then node checks whether this dependency package is available in `node_modules` folder or not..

so in your case it is not and that is the reason for the error..

Now, add the dependency package details in the `package.json` or do an `npm i --save themodule`

Comment: Is this module available in your node_modules folder ? Can you check

Comment: You mean in the node_modules folder of my project? No it's not since I install it globally.

Comment: @GBMan by installing globally (on windows machines anyway) you are simply installing to a node modules folder on your user profile instead of one of the local project folder. Can you check in a location like the following `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

Comment: Can you set a system variable NODE_PATH to your system node_modules path you gave above... or use “requireg” module to pull globally installed packages

Comment: Your global packages are not available to your project yet... so if you want them to directly work for you in your project.. create a system variable and point it to the bode_modules global folder..

Comment: @DublinDev The module is here.

Comment: @gopigorantala, I create a system variable NODE_PATH, this didn't change anything, and I look the values of PATH. The path for the global node_modules is inside so... I doesn't understand yet... I must resign myself to work in local...

Comment: If this is the case then i will wipe the node_modules folder, unistall node and start again..