# Access browser console from a terminal?

Tags: browser, development-environment

Is it possible to access Developer Tools (Chrome/Firefox) console from a Linux terminal for scripting purposes?

I am trying to access an AngularJS application's variables from my browser so that I can quickly navigate across files. For example, I could ask for the `state`, and its related `partial`, `controller` etc; once I find the result, I would open that file in my editor.

The other alternatives I am exploring is to use some kind of [headless browser](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md). There is also [devtools-protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) which is used by tools like [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) for programmatic access to Chrome Developer Tools.

A simple Node REPL would have been enough, but the problem is that I will have to figure a lot of stuff manually if I have load my site's JavaScript files in to REPL.

Does anyone have some good suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to use or write a [JavaScript parser](https://esprima.org/), which is only fun for a very limited set of individuals, I suggest taking
advantage of the thriving headless Chrome community. Grabbing JS variables with
[puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#usage) is straightforward after some boilerplate node code.
It's also shockingly (but not "blazingly") fast.

**Before running the code:**

- Have node js and npm working on your machine
- [Install `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) for parsing JSON in the shell. It is available in most package managers, so `brew install jq` or `sudo apt install jq` etc should work.
- Install Puppeteer in whichever directory these scripts are going to live in with `npm i puppeteer`

  - To avoid getting into the weeds, I'll skip over the [global node imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package) topic here.

A file like this is all you need to get started with Puppeteer. I added comments to the key areas.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

;(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  // Replace the line above with this statement a fun show
  // const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  //   headless: false,
  //   devtools: true,
  // })
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  // Arbitrarily choosing SO for the demo, replace with your website
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/')
  // Or use an argument:
  // const uri = process.argv[2]
  // await page.goto(process.argv[0])

  const retrievedData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    // This block has the page context, which is almost identical to being in the console
    // except for some of the console's supplementary APIs.

    // Get the URL host name and path separately
    const { origin, pathname } = window.location;

    // Get the title in a silly way, for demonstration purposes only
    const title = document.querySelector('title').textContent

    // More interesting - save data from the `StackExchange` object from `window`
    const { options: soOptions } = window.StackExchange

    // Return an object literal with data for the shell script 
    return {
      origin,
      pathname,
      soOptions,
    }
  })

  // Convert the object from the browser eval to JSON to parse with with jq later
  const retrievedJSON = JSON.stringify(retrievedData, null, 4)

  // console.log writes to stdout in node
  console.log(retrievedJSON)

  await browser.close()
})()
```

Note the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top, which makes the shell understand to run it with `node`.

If we make this file executable and run it:

```sh
chmod +x get-so-data.js
./get-so-data.js
```

We have a CLI utility that will provide a JSON string of data from the JavaScript global execution context of the website. Here are some small generic shell examples.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Confirm that jq understands the result (should pretty print with ANSI colors):
./get-so-data.js | jq
# {
#   Many data...
# }

# Check if user is logged in (the user is our node script in a sandboxed browser, so no):
./get-so-data.js | jq '.soOptions.user.isRegistered' 
# null

# Tell the time, according to StackExchange's server clock (linux only):
./get-so-data.js | jq '.soOptions.serverTime' | date -d $(echo -n '@' && cat --)
# Fri 11 Sep 2020 04:37:02 PM PDT

# Open a subset of the JSON payload returned by Puppeteer in the default editor:
./get-so-data.js | jq '.soOptions' | $EDITOR --
# or VS Code specifically
./get-so-data.js | jq '.soOptions' | code --

# ...
```

As long as the JavaScript side of the equation is returning enough info to construct a file path, you can open files in your editor based on JavaScript in a browser.

**The shell date example takes about 1.5 seconds** on a three-year-old Chromebook
from within a [Linux (Beta) container](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en)
using 25mbps public wifi. Your mileage will vary depending on the performance of
the site you're debugging and the steps in the script.

```sh
$ time ./get-so-data.js | jq '.soOptions.serverTime' | date -d $(echo -ne '@' && cat --)
Fri 11 Sep 2020 04:43:24 PM PDT

real    0m1.515s
user    0m0.945s
sys     0m0.383s

$ time ./get-so-data.js | jq '.soOptions.serverTime' | date -d $(echo -ne '@' && cat --)
Fri 11 Sep 2020 04:43:30 PM PDT

real    0m1.755s
user    0m0.999s
sys     0m0.433s

$ time ./get-so-data.js | jq '.soOptions.serverTime' | date -d $(echo -ne '@' && cat --)
Fri 11 Sep 2020 04:43:33 PM PDT

real    0m1.422s
user    0m0.802s
sys     0m0.361s
```

### Resources

- [`jq` official tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/)
- [Puppeteer page.evaluate docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.3.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args)
- [Try Puppeteer in a browser](https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/)
- [yargs - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) (for more advanced command line arguments in the node script)