# How to add module to package.json if it is already a global package?

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

I would like to have `redux-thunk` in my `package.json`, but use the globally installed version (not in my project-specific `node_modules` folder). Do I need to add it to my `package.json` manually? Using `npm install -g redux-thunk` doesn't add the package to my `package.json`. Also, when I run my react app and import `redux-thunk`, I get a `module not found error` even though `redux-thunk` is installed globally. Is this because I am required to have the package in my project's `node_modules` folder and not in the global installation location?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS require a global module/package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package)

Comment: However, typically you wouldn't use a globally installed package in your local project. Instead you would install it in your local projects _node_modules_ directory. For example; **1)** `cd` to your project directory. **2)** Then run `npm install redux-thunk ` _(i.e. without the `-g` option)_

Comment: That question was helpful but does that translate over to react? Also, would it be possible to install it globally _and_ add it to package.json (without installing in the specific project)

Answer (score 0):

the `-g` flag installs it globally. If you want to add it to your `package.json` file go to the directory where your `package.json` file is and run:

```
npm install redux-thunk
```

Comment: But if I do `npm install redux-thunk` then it will download and add the package in my `node_modules` folder, which isn't what I want because I want to use the global version. Is there a way to get the module in `package.json` and still only install the global module?