# Why this package installed by npm is not found

Tags: javascript, npm

I am working on Debian Stable Linux which is updated and working very well.

I have installed a [compute-pcorr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compute-pcorr) package globally with following npm command:

```
$ sudo npm install compute-pcorr -g
```

It is listed with following npm command:

```
$  npm list -g --depth=0 
/usr/local/lib
├── compute-pcorr@1.0.0
└── ml-stat@1.3.3
```

I am now trying following code demo code from its [homepage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compute-pcorr):

```
var pcorr = require( 'compute-pcorr@1.0.0' ); 

var x = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]; 
var y = [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ];

var mat = pcorr( x, y );
Console.log("Correlation Matrix: "+ mat)
```

However, when I run above code, I get error:

```
$ node compute_pcorr_usage.js 

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'compute-pcorr@1.0.0'
```

Following in code is also not working:

```
var pcorr = require( 'compute-pcorr' );
```

I also tried to reinstall package with following command, but error persists:

```
sudo npm install compute-pcorr -g --save
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: You also have to add it locally by ```npm install compute-pcorr```. I tried and it worked.

Comment: So, I should not install globally with -g option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS require a global module/package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package)

Comment: Yes. There's no need.

Comment: Global packages are usually for things like command line tools, which after you install you get a command which can be used everywhere, like `tsc`, `pkg`, etc. For dependencies which your project depends on, i.e. the code need to be ship with your project, you install it locally.

Comment: Have you created `package.json` using `npm init` before `npm install compute-pcorr`?

Comment: No, but my code is now working!  package.json has been automatically created and populated.

Comment: What is the role of `--save` option? When is that needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens when the library is not installed locally.
Try installing locally in your directory with the command `npm install compute-pcorr`
There's no need of installing globally via `-g`

Comment: You can delete this comment as it is now in your answer!

Comment: Please check all post and don't add what is already there.