# Everytime i create a new node react app i have to download all packages which i have used before ? is there some fix for this?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, node-modules

I have some 5 react projects, and in all of them i have to seperately add all the packages.
I have been following some youtube video in that this guy doesn't have node_modules folder in his directory but still he can use all of these in his projects.

I just want to know the way i can achieve that.

Comment: Some IDEs will hide the `node_modules/` folder, but there's installing the dependencies as a global dependency (using `npm i -g`). Overall I would consider it best-practice to actually contain your node application in the way you're currently doing. It has the added benefits that dependencies of one project will not affect dependencies of another. If you install some dependency version `1.2.3` for project `A`, and `2.1.4` for project `B`, you'll need to redownload every time you switch projects or risk version mismatching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS require a global module/package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package)

Answer (score 0):

There are majorly two ways to install a package for your node applications:

1. locally
2. globally

For local, you can use `npm i <package-name>` which would install the package only for your project directory.

For global, you can use `npm i -g <package-name>` which would install the package globally and the package would be accessible on your machine regardless of your project.

In brief, use `npm i -g <package-name>` if you want your node package to be commonly available across all projects.