# How can I use globally installed Volta package in Node script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, volta

I installed `jsonlint` globally with `volta install jsonlint`, but when trying to execute a node script with `node json.js` as below, it is not recognized

A standalone Script (not part of any module):

```js
var Jsonlint = require("jsonlint")
const jsonString = '{"name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York"}';

JsonLint.format(jsonString, (err, formattedJson) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(formattedJson);
  }
});
```

Error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'jsonlint'
Require stack:
- /Users/gopala.akshintala/Desktop/json.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gopala.akshintala/Desktop/json.js:1:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/gopala.akshintala/Desktop/json.js' ]
}
```

But I can see jsonlint is recognized in terminal globally:

```
$ jsonlint -v
1.6.3
```

I am expecting that `require` should pick jsonlint from here

```
$ which jsonlint
~/.volta/bin/jsonlint
```

What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15646750/3966682

Comment: Probably better to add `jsonlint` as a project-local dependency, though

Comment: @d4nyll I did try that NODE_PATH suggestion but didn't work, and my script is standalone