# How to install a specific version of Node on Ubuntu/Debian?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, n

I would like to install NodeJS version 0.8.18 on Ubuntu 12.04. I tried to install the newest version and then reverting to 0.8.18 by using `nvm`, but when I run my code apparently there is some problem with the packages installed and the two versions (latest and 0.8.18). Since I don't know how to solve that problem, I cleaned the machine from the Node installation and thought about installing directly the version I'm interested in (v0.8.18).

Comment: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.18/ has some dist files, did you try those?

Comment: Hi, not really. I'm not really into Ubuntu and dist files, so I don't even know how to use them. Anyways thanks, I'm checking how to do it and see if I can use them!

Comment: There is API change from 0.8.x to 0.10.x. So be sure to check the changes. Also not just node, various packages for e.g. `express` have API changes too.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Chris Lea has 0.8.23 in his ppa repo.

This package let you add a repository to apt-get: (You can also do this manually)

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Add Chris Lea's repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js-legacy
```

Update apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Node.js:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.8.23-1chl1~precise1
```

I think (feel free to edit) the version number is optional if you only add node.js-legacy. If you add both legacy and ppa/chris-lea/node.js you most likely need to add the version.

Comment: `sudo apt-cache showpkg nodejs` - you can use this command for show available versions `sudo apt-get install npm` - add npm manager to your computer

Comment: If you're looking to install newer versions, like 0.11.x: (1) `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js-devel` (2) Update: run `sudo apt-get update` (3) Then, to list the latest packages: `sudo apt-cache showpkg nodejs` (4) For example, to install 0.11.14: `sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.11.14-1chl1~trusty1` This is often a great way to install Node with harmony support. Remember to use the --harmony flag when you run Node.

Comment: How the heck do you figure out this part of the version: `-1chl1~precise1`?

Answer (score 139):

The `n` module worked for me.

Run this code to clear npm’s cache, install n, and install the latest stable version of Node:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

See: http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/
And: https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

To install a specific version of node:

`sudo n 18.17.1`

To check what version:

`node -v`

You might need to restart

Comment: Not a huge fan of the single-letter name, but this solution definitely works and is trivially easy!

Comment: You could always alias it: `alias noonoonaanaanoonoo='n'` ;)
`

Comment: Didn't work for me. But after some searching, a similarly simple solution that worked was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45584004/3673329

Comment: Found a similar answer somewhere else but the restart statement was missing there, it took me hours until I saw ur answer, restarted the machine, and finally, node was pointing to the newer version.

Comment: Only this worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks!

Comment: I am in the same boat as https://stackoverflow.com/users/12923941/pwj. This is a way better solution than others out there for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Thank you!

Answer (score 58):

#### NVM (Node Version manager)

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Advantages:

- allows you to use multiple versions of Node and without sudo
- is analogous to Ruby RVM and Python Virtualenv, widely considered best practice in Ruby and Python communities
- downloads a pre-compiled binary where possible, and if not it downloads the source and compiles one for you

Tested in Ubuntu 17.10:

```bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 0.9.0
nvm install 0.9.9
nvm use 0.9.0
node --version
#v0.9.0
nvm use 0.9.9
node --version
#v0.9.9
```

For the particular case of the most recent long term support version (recommended if you can choose):

```bash
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
npm --version
npm install --global vaca
vaca
```

Since the sourcing has to be done for every new shell, the install script hacks adds some auto sourcing to the end of your `.barshrc`. That works, but I prefer to remove the auto-added one and add my own:

```bash
f="$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"
if [ -r "$f" ]; then
  . "$f" &>'/dev/null'
  nvm use --lts &>'/dev/null'
fi
```

With this setup, you get for example:

```bash
which node
```

gives:

```
/home/ciro/.nvm/versions/node/v0.9.0/bin/node
```

and:

```
which vaca
```

gives:

```
/home/ciro/.nvm/versions/node/v0.9.0/bin/vaca
```

and if we want to use the globally installed module:

```bash
npm link vaca
node -e 'console.log(require.resolve("vaca"))'
```

gives:

```
/home/ciro/.nvm/versions/node/v0.9.0/lib/node_modules/vaca/index.js
```

as mentioned at:

- [NodeJS require a global module/package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package)
- [How do I import global modules in Node? I get "Error: Cannot find module <module>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970793/how-do-i-import-global-modules-in-node-i-get-error-cannot-find-module-module)

so we see that everything is completely contained inside the specific node version.

For projects however, you are better off just using packages installed locally under `node_modules` and `npx` for executable to be able to have independent versions across projects, global usage is mostly for the Node executable itself and global CLI utilities not specific to any project.

### Setting the NPM version

Simply:

```
npm install npm@6.14.13 -g
```

The executable is placed inside the current NVM version, so everything remains nice and isolated, e.g.:

```
which npm
```

gives something like:

```
/home/ciro/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/npm
```

[How can I change the version of npm using nvm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755841/how-can-i-change-the-version-of-npm-using-nvm)

Comment: At least the recent version of `nvm` (0.35) is updating `.bashrc` automatically. It appends there sourcing of `nvm.sh` and also bash completions.

Comment: @DawidFerenczyRogožan yes, thanks, I've clarified that in the answer.

Comment: 6 years later (nearly) still best most concise answer I could find, great stuff!

Comment: 6 years and a month later, i got spanked for not reading instructions. For node 18, it should be piped to "bash" I think.  [says here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm?tab=readme-ov-file#install--update-script)

Comment: @RichardDomingo thanks updated, yes, their error message is quite funny.

Answer (score 42):

It is possible to install specific version of nodejs from nodejs official distribution with using `dpkg`.

- Check the version of you ubuntu distribution, `cat /etc/lsb-release`.
- Check architecture of your os, `uname -m`.
- Download preferred version of debian package from nodejs official site.

  - For 4.x, https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/
  - For 5.x, https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/
  - For 0.12.x, https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.12/pool/main/n/nodejs/
- Be careful to check `nodejs-dbg` or `nodejs` in filename.

For example, currently recent 4.x version is 4.2.4, but you can install previous 4.2.3 version.

```
curl -s -O https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs_4.2.3-1nodesource1~trusty1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install rlwrap
sudo dpkg -i nodejs_4.2.3-1nodesource1~trusty1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: For some reason the **curl** command didn't work for me, so I used **wget** instead. But the process as a whole worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

Try this way. This worked me.

1. **wget nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.36/node-v0.10.36-linux-x64.tar.gz**(download file)
2. Go to the directory where the Node.js binary was downloaded to, and then run command i.e, **sudo tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf node-v0.10.36-linux-x64.tar.gz** to install the Node.js binary package in “/usr/local/”.
3. You can check:-

   ```
   $ node -v
    v0.10.36 
   $ npm -v
    1.4.28
   ```

Answer (score 17):

In ubuntu specific version of node can be installed with help of nvm

install nvm

```
sudo apt install curl 
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash 
source ~/.bashrc
```

To install a particular version of node, use the command nvm install and add the number of the version.

```
nvm install 10.15.2
node -v
```

Comment: what is 'source'?

Answer (score 10):

I imagine many directed here are looking for this to add to a `Dockerfile`

```
RUN set -x \
    && curl -sL 'https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x' | bash - \
    && apt-get -y install nodejs \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: How can specify exact version with it?

Comment: Seems nodesource only use major versions: https://github.com/nodejs/Release

Answer (score 8):

Say you want to install Node 10,

Firstly, download and execute the Node.js 10.x installer:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
```

This will add a source file for the official Node.js 10.x repo, grabs the signing key

Once the installer is done doing it’s thing, you will need to install (or upgrade) Node.js:

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Comment: This was a good one, but the script got deprecated, see: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/tree/master#installation-instructions, for the latest version of the script.

Answer (score 6):

version 0.10 is also avaible with this ppa

```
apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

install nodejs with:

```
apt-get install nodejs=0.10.25-1chl1~precise1
```

Thanks to my friend [Julian Xhokaxhiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518095/julian-xhokaxhiu)

Comment: This is command giving error to me on ubuntu 14.10 E: Version '0.10.15' for 'nodejs' was not found

Answer (score 5):

yes, its a duplicate answer but I insist using n module to install a specific version(following commands installs node version 6.9.5).

```
npm install -g  n
n 6.9.5
```

Answer (score 4):

> **NOTE:** you can use NVM software to do this in a more nodejs fashionway.
>   However i got issues in one machine that didn't let me use NVM. So i
>   have to look for an alternative ;-)

You can manually download and install.

go to nodejs > download > other releases
http://nodejs.org/dist/

choose the version you are looking for 
http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.18/

choose distro files corresponding your environmment and download (take care of 32bits/64bits version).
Example: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.18/node-v0.8.18-linux-x64.tar.gz

Extract files and follow instructions on README.md :

> #### To build:
>
> Prerequisites (Unix only):
>
> ```
> * Python 2.6 or 2.7
> * GNU Make 3.81 or newer
> * libexecinfo (FreeBSD and OpenBSD only)
> ```
>
> Unix/Macintosh:
>
> ```
> ./configure
> make
> make install
> ```
>
> If your python binary is in a non-standard location or has a
>   non-standard name, run the following instead:
>
> ```
> export PYTHON=/path/to/python
> $PYTHON ./configure
> make
> make install
> ```
>
> Windows:
>
> ```
> vcbuild.bat
> ```
>
> #### To run the tests:
>
> Unix/Macintosh:
>
> ```
> make test
> ```
>
> Windows:
>
> ```
> vcbuild.bat test
> ```
>
> #### To build the documentation:
>
> ```
> make doc
> ```
>
> #### To read the documentation:
>
> ```
> man doc/node.1
> ```

Maybe you want to (must to) move the folder to a more apropiate place like /usr/lib/nodejs/node-v0.8.18/ then create a Symbolic Lynk on /usr/bin to get acces to your install from anywhere.

```
sudo mv /extracted/folder/node-v0.8.18 /usr/lib/nodejs/node-v0.8.18
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nodejs/node-v0.8.18/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

And if you want different release in the same machine you can use debian alternatives. Proceed in the same way posted before to download a second release. For example the latest release.

http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ -> http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v0.10.28-linux-x64.tar.gz

Move to your favorite destination, the same of the rest of release you want to install.

```
sudo mv /extracted/folder/node-v0.10.28 /usr/lib/nodejs/node-v0.10.28
```

Follow instructions of the README.md file. Then update the alternatives, for each release you have dowload install the alternative with.

```
sudo update-alternatives    --install genname symlink  altern  priority  [--slave  genname  symlink altern]
          Add a group of alternatives  to  the  system.   genname  is  the
          generic  name  for  the  master link, symlink is the name of its
          symlink  in  the  alternatives  directory,  and  altern  is  the
          alternative being introduced for the master link.  The arguments
          after  --slave  are  the  generic  name,  symlink  name  in  the
          alternatives  directory  and alternative for a slave link.  Zero
          or more --slave options, each followed by three  arguments,  may
          be specified.

          If   the   master   symlink  specified  exists  already  in  the
          alternatives system’s records, the information supplied will  be
          added  as a new set of alternatives for the group.  Otherwise, a
          new group, set to  automatic  mode,  will  be  added  with  this
          information.   If  the group is in automatic mode, and the newly
          added alternatives’ priority is higher than any other  installed
          alternatives  for  this  group,  the symlinks will be updated to
          point to the newly added alternatives.
```

for example:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/lib/nodejs/node-v0.10.28 0 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz node.1.gz /usr/lib/nodejs/node-v0.10.28/share/man/man1/node.1
```

Then you can use `update-alternatives --config node` to choose between any number of releases instaled in your machine.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, according to [this page](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) in the wiki of the nodejs github repo, Chris Lea's PPA (mentioned in several other answers) has been superseded by the [NodeSource](https://nodesource.com/) distributions as the main way of installing nodejs from source in Ubuntu:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

This is supported for the three latest (at the time of writing this) LTS versions of Ubuntu: 10.04 (lucid), 12.04 LTS (precise) and 14.04 (trusty).

I'm not sure this will help in installing an old version of nodejs, but I'm putting this here in case it helps others who needed to install a specific (newer) version of nodejs that isn't included in their distro's repositories.

Comment: OP asks for a speciifc node version.

Answer (score 3):

To install a specific version of nodejs in Ubuntu you can use below commands, just specify and replace the version number, for example, node_12.x will fetch the latest of 12.

```
curl https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x $(lsb_release -sc) main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: Specifying the minor version like node_12.16.3 doesn't work. I just tried with node_12.18.4 which is a LTS version as of today.

Answer (score 2):

FYI the available version for raring in Chris Lea's repo is currently 0.8.25

`sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.8.25-2chl1~raring1`

Comment: The version keeps changing evidently.  How do I see which version is the right one?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of available builds for debian: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/tree/master/deb

For this example, lets assume you want version 14 (LTS at the time of writing)

We can [download this script from github](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/deb/setup_14.x), execute it and install the version of node we want. For security reasons it's a good idea to read the script prior to executing it.

```sh
curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodesource/distributions/master/deb/setup_14.x | bash
apt-get install -y nodejs # may or may not require sudo based on your setup
```

I like this approach because it doesn't require extraneous dependencies like nvm to target specific versions

If you are building for a different distro or architecture you can find more builds here https://nodejs.org/dist/

Answer (score 0):

The Node.js project recently pushed out a new stable version with the 0.10.0 release
Use the following command on Ubuntu 13x
sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.10.18-1chl1~raring1

Answer (score 0):

Install nvm using the following commands in the same order.nvm stands for node version manager.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall libssl-dev
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash
```

In case the above command does not work add -k after -o- .It should be as below:

```
curl -o- -k  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash
```

Then `nvm ls-remote` to see the available versions.
In case you get N/A in return,run the following.

```
export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=http://nodejs.org/dist
```

alternatively you can run the following commands too

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This         loads nvm bash_completion
```

Then `nvm install #.#.#` replacing # by version(say nvm 8.9.4)
finally `nvm use #.#.#`