# npm install error after installing nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a problem to install the npm, These are my errors, there are lot of errors , but i paste some of these here, please tell me what should i do?I have already installed nodejs , mongodb and all..

```
npm WARN package.json hublin@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json awesome-collaborative-editor@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json awesome-module@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json awesome-yjs@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json chokidar@1.5.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json karma-mocha@0.1.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 No README data
npm WARN package.json karma-rawfixtures-preprocessor@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json om-email-invitation@0.0.3 No README data
npm WARN package.json om-invitation@0.0.2 No README data
npm WARN package.json om-mailer@0.0.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json trim@0.0.1 No repository field.
```

Comment: Duplicate of [npm WARN package.json: No repository field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field). The short answer is that you don't need to worry about these warnings. Many packages are missing these optional entries and it won't impact your app.

Comment: try to this command sudo npm update -g on terminal

Comment: Then why npm start is not working?These errors:

Comment: npm start

> hublin@0.1.0 start /home/macoye/meetings
> node server.js

Logger DailyRotateFile is disabled
Logger File is disabled
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
error: uncaughtException: Cannot find module 'awesome-yjs' 
{ date: 'Fri May 27 2016 12:29:24 GMT+0530 (IST)',
  process:

Comment: I want specific version of nodejs that is 0.10.36, i i try to run above command, then it updates my nodejs

Comment: please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898001/installing-a-specific-node-version-in-ubuntu

Comment: npm ERR! awesome-yjs@0.0.0 postinstall: `./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the awesome-yjs@0.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the awesome-yjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls awesome-yjs

Comment: which os you are using

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 using

Comment: And i amtrying to setup hublin, so that i am trying to run all commands , and i am unable to connect http://localhost:8080, because i am unable to properly install npm and all

Comment: I am also unable to understand this point:Copy the sample db.json configuration file and adapt it to your need (especially the mongodb URL if you do not use default parameters from step 2)

cp config/db.json.sample config/db.json

Comment: npm ERR! awesome-yjs@0.0.0 postinstall: `./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the awesome-yjs@0.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the awesome-yjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.