# Nodejs always installing 4.2.6

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04

I am installing latest version of nodejs in my localhost. But system is always installing the 4.2.6 version.How can i install the latest version.

Commands i have used:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

After installing i have checked:

```
node -v
```

Result:

```
v4.2.6
```

Output of `apt-cache policy nodejs`:

```
Installed: 4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4
Candidate: 4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4
Version table:
*** 4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4 500
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 
Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

OR

Can anyone send the installation steps for installing from

```
node-v8.2.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

file.

Thanks

Comment: What does `which node` return?

Comment: You probably have an older version in your path somewhere other than where you are installing.

Comment: @robertklep Which node returns /usr/local/bin/node.Thanks

Comment: The Nodesource version should be installed as `/usr/bin/node`, try `/usr/bin/node -v`. I'm not sure what installed `/usr/local/bin/node`, but it's getting in the way. Try uninstalling it.

Comment: @robertklep  Ok , thank you so much , let me check.

Comment: @robertklep I have tried uninstalling and reinstalled still installing nodejs 4.2.6 always.Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that installing the `setup_8.x` script actually succeeds? Can you add the output of `apt-cache policy nodejs` to your question? It should show which repository is being used to install the `nodejs` package.

Comment: @robertklep I have updated the question, please check.Thanks

Comment: @youv it looks like the Nodesource repository isn't getting installed properly. Does the `curl ... | sudo ...` command line show any errors?

Comment: Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: .. This is the output am getting.

Comment: Seems like `curl` can't resolve the host `deb.nodesource.com`, which is ultimately the source of your problem.

Comment: Ok, Could you please send the installation steps for installing from the tar file , node-v8.2.1-linux-x64.tar.xz

Comment: @Youv look here: https://fusion809.github.io/howto-install-nodejs/#toc2

Comment: @robertklep Ok, i will check that.Thanks

Comment: I wonder why i got down-vote for this question.Am sure this question is clear and genuine. :(

Comment: @youv strictly speaking, it's off topic on StackOverflow, I think that's why someone downvoted it.

Comment: Ok,thanks.I have installed node using nvm.When i type node -v , it is displaying the version as 8.2.1 but nodejs -v displays nothing.Is nodejs installed ? node same as nodejs? nvm install v8.2.1 is enough?

Comment: I don't use `nvm` to "replace" a global Node.js installation myself, only to install older versions of Node to test code with. But `node` is the name of the executable, `nodejs` isn't really used (as executable name, I mean; the _package_ is still called `nodejs`, though).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Linux/Mac systems, there is no better way than [nvm - Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Install:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Then, usage is as simple as:

```
nvm install 8.0
nvm use 8.0
```

If after reboot you will see old version, use `nvm alias` to set your version as default one.

Note: If you're a happy user of new M1 Apple chip, install version 15 of Node.js with nvm, it supports it out of the box.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply

Comment: you also have `n` which is similar

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys if you have Ubuntu 16 try this instructions. It worked for me perfectly.Also provide your account password whenever asked in this process.

1. sudo su -c "echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
2. sudo su -c "echo 'deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
3. sudo apt-get update
4. apt-cache policy nodejs
   Check if the versions listed has node 8
5. sudo apt-get install nodejs
6. nodejs -v
   check the node version installed

This shall successfully install nodejs version 8 on your system. If you wish any other version, then change the version on step 1 and 2 it shall work successfully.

Answer (score 1):

For me - the solution was on this page:

Ref: https://websiteforstudents.com/install-the-latest-node-js-and-nmp-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-lts/

**... for the Latest release, add this PPA..**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
```

**To install the LTS release, use this PPA**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver LTS ... so I needed version 8

Answer (score 0):

Current LTS instructions:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Courtesy of https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions

Answer (score 0):

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

sudo apt-get update

#Use this to remove the Previous Nodejs from Your device and then try again with Installing NVM