# how to install older version of node in ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I want to install node `v=14.8.0` and npm `v=6.14.8` for my project. How can install it instead of the latest version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a specific version of Node on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898001/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-node-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I will try, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I'd highly recommend you to install `Node.js` and `npm` on `Ubuntu` using `nvm`.**

> **Node Version Manager**
> **nvm** (Node Version Manager) is a tool that allows you to download and install Node. js. Check if you have it installed via nvm --version . npm (Node Package Manager) is a tool that allows you to install javascript packages

Please visit and follow the steps from this link: [How to Install Node.js and npm on Ubuntu](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18.04/) to achieve your goal.