# install specific version on nodejs on ubuntu 21.10

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, apt

I'm new to `ubuntu 21.10` and recently I use `ubuntu 20.04`
after upgrading mu node package was upgraded to `12.22.0` and my node packages completely messed up
now I want to install `node 10.19.0` on my ubuntu how can id do this?

Comment: Does this solves your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898001/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-node-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can downgrade **npm** by simple pasting a needed version:

For example:

```
npm install -g npm@3.10.10
```

Be sure that it's downgraded:

```
npm -v
```

2. To downgrade **nodejs**, you can also do so by simple pasting a needed version.

For example:

```
$ npm install -g n
$ n 6.10.3
```

Be sure that it's downgraded:

```
$ node -v
v6.10.3
```

If it doesn't show up a needed version, you can try to run all commands above with admin privileges.