# Cannot Initialize a Vite App due to syntax error on internal files

Tags: vite

I'm trying to run `npm init vite` on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and node v12.22.9, but it gaves me this error

```
file:///home/giacomo/.npm/_npx/2c4a09cdd3a6d615/node_modules/create-vite/index.js:296
return targetDir?.trim().replace(/\/+$/g, '')
               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path /home/giacomo/Scrivania/html/3DWebApp
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c create-vite

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/giacomo/.npm/_logs/2022-07-25T05_58_55_401Z-debug-0.log
```

I've tried other methods like `npm init @vitejs/app` or `npm create @vitejs/app` but they're deprecated.
There's a way i can manually fix it or there is another method to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error points to the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) syntax (`?.`), which is not supported in Node 12.22.9. That feature was introduced in Node 14.

Also [Vite 3 docs indicate the minimum Node version required](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project):

> #### Compatibility Note
>
> Vite requires [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) version >=14.18.0. However, some templates require a higher Node.js version to work, please upgrade if your package manager warns about it.

You should upgrade your version of Node (e.g., using [`n`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45726068/6277151)). The current latest version is Node 18.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, i had the same problem while using the node version `14.19.3`..

Then, i upgraded the node version to `v16.10.0` - It solved and the app is running fine now. Thanks.