# Docker Node.js container error unexpected token '.' when trying to run the container

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu

I am currently learning Docker and trying to follow this course (https://devopswithdocker.com/part-1/section-6/) to develop my skills.
Although I was able to do everything until now, I am stuck on this exercise (1.12 down the page):

I have made a Dockerfile to containerize the project (exampel-frontend) by following the instructions from the read-me file ( https://github.com/docker-hy/material-applications/blob/main/example-frontend/README.md) with the following code (actually I have written almost similar but this is the solution that can be found here: https://github.com/oneiromancy/devops-with-docker

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && curl https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN apt-get install -y npm && npm install && npm run build && npm install -g serve

CMD ["npx", "serve", "-s", "-l", "8080", "build"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

However, when I build and run the container :

```
docker build . -t hello-frontend
docker run -p 8080:8080 hello-frontend
```

I get the following error:

```
file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/serve/build/main.js:169
      const ipAddress = request.socket.remoteAddress?.replace("::ffff:", "") ?? "unknown";
                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
```

Could you help me to fix it as I need this application to be running for the following exercises ...

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't got that invalid '.' in your code or the code pulled down via npm? Examine `main.js` at line 169 as indicated in the error. Perhaps post the code here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers! The final version that helped me solve all the errors was :

```
FROM node:16  
WORKDIR /usr/src/app  

COPY package*.json ./  

RUN npm install 

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 8080 

RUN npm list 
RUN npm run build && npm install -g serve  

CMD ["npx", "serve", "-s", "-l", "8080", "build"]
```

The problem I was facing was coming mostly from the fact that `COPY package*.json ./`  was missing in my Dockerfile.

I found out about it by adding : RUN `npm list`

In case anyone has the same problem ...

Answer (score 1):

Your node version is less than Node 12.22.9.

**syntax (?.)**

That feature was introduced in Node 14.

You should upgrade your version of Node. The current version of **Node v19**, but **Active LTS version is v18** version https://nodejs.org/en

This link is helpful for update node version [How to install a specific version of Node on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898001/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-node-on-ubuntu/45726068#45726068)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of basing your image on `ubuntu:latest` and installing Node 14.x yourself (which reaches end of life in May), you might want to consider switching to basing it on `node:lts` which is an image that already has the latest long-term-service Node version installed.

Then you can cut your Dockerfile down to

```
FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY . .

RUN npm install && npm run build && npm install -g serve

CMD ["npx", "serve", "-s", "-l", "8080", "build"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

Currently, the `lts` version of Node is version 18. If you, for some reason, need to run Node 14, you can use the `node:14` image instead.

Comment: Thank you as your answer greatly helped me to figure out what was wrong