# How to set NODE_PATH using .env Nodejs

Tags: node.js

Here's my architecture:

```
.
├── app.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── controller
    │   └── index.controller.js
    └── route
        └── index.route.js
```

**.env**

```
NODE_PATH=./src
```

**index.route.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const Router = express.Router();

const { root } = require('controller/index.controller');      <--- Failed

Router.get('/', root);

module.exports = {
  Router
};
```

**index.controller.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const root = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('root');
};

console.log('controller');

module.exports = {
  root
};
```

I would like to use an **.env** file with a **NODE_PATH** to easily import module in my .js file and avoid those kind of pattern **../../../folder/folder/module.js**

However when I do **node app.js**. Node doesn't seem to care about the .env
An error occur in **index.route.js**

> Error: Cannot find module 'controller/index.controller'

Does someone can explain me why node doesn't care about the NODE_PATH I set ?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to refer below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185627/node-js-node-path-environment-variable. It must work for you. Instead of configuring in .env file we can give it in scripts of package.json

Comment: I just try, it work. :) But I'm curious to know if it's possible only by using the .env file ?

Comment: im on the same boat as you, did you ever find a solution? ive managed to do this with react in the past, but for some reason on a clean node install backend it aint working ><

Answer (score 0):

To access .env file, assign process.env.NODE_PATH to a variable like below

```
let temp = process.env.NODE_PATH
```

now in your require statement

```
require(temp + '/controller/index.controller');
```

Note- I haven't tested it, but it should work

Comment: It doesn't work. In your require statement "temp" it's part of the string so node doesn't know that it should represent process.env.NODE_PATH

Comment: But you got the idea, i hope

Comment: Oh yeah I got the idea haha but is there an other way to do without use process.env.NODE_PATH in the code ?