# How to install Node.js with yarn package manager in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I would like to install Node.js with yarn.pkg in my Dockerfile.
The Dockerfile is for a Laravel8/PHP8 project.

This is my actual try:

```
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        nodejs \
        yarn \
        mysql-client
```

If I try it this way, I got this output on my shell:

```sh
 => CACHED [ 8/20] RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [ 9/20] RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -                                                                                                                                                                             0.4s
------
 > [ 9/20] RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -:
#12 0.331 Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
#12 0.384 gpg: Segmentation fault
#12 0.384 no valid OpenPGP data found.
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -]: exit code: 2
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?
If you need more information about it, please let me know.

Regards,
Manny

Comment: Since this question isn't really about either PHP or Laravel, please remove those tags.

Comment: Done! Thank's for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... `NPM` (Node package manager) is installed along with `Node.js`, and `Yarn` is just a module that is installed like `npm install -g yarn`

Simply edit and use what [another post mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546198/8740349) like:

```
ENV NODE_VERSION=12.6.0
RUN apt install -y curl
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version

RUN npm install -g yarn
```

> **Note** that this is the best way I know to manage `Node`'s version.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've posted my complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Top-Master, thank's a lot for your input. It has helped me a lot to find my solution.

Here it is...
I have used the Dockerfile you posted above and made some small changes:

```
ENV NODE_VERSION=16.5
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
    && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
    && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
    && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"

RUN npm install -g yarn
```

The problem was, the `RUN npm install -g yarn` command run into an error and the build fails. After some googling around I've found this webpage https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm.
They recommend, that npm should be installed separately because of the directory structure and user rights. They are not the same if you install npm with Node.js together.

So I've done this:

```
ENV NODE_VERSION=16.5
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
    && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
    && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
    && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        npm
RUN npm install -g yarn
```

For me (and I hope for many other people too) it works now :)

Thank's again!
Have a nice time!