# Hardhat in docker container

Tags: python, docker, hardhat

I have the below simple Dockerfile, i need the container to contain hardhat, how can I install hardhat inside the container?

```
FROM python:3.9


WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN pip install -r env/requirements.txt

CMD ["python3","main.py"]
```

ability to run `npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition-ethers` in docker

Comment: You will have to install node in the Dockerfile. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546198/5666087 for some advice on how to do that. As it is now, the container does not include node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's this simple

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs npm && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN npm install --save-dev hardhat


RUN pip install -r env/requirements.txt


CMD ["python3","main.py"]
```